# Can I acess a docker container via RDP?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, devops

I want to acess docker container via RDP.
Also, I am not able to assign a public IP.
While creating the container it gets a private IP.
So is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: A little tip about markdown: you need two spaces at the end of a line before hitting Enter once to get a soft linebreak. Or you can have an empty line by hitting Enter twice, which will result in a new paragraph.

Comment: You should be able to use the ordinary `docker run -p` option to make an RDP port accessible.  But, it's very unusual for a Docker container to be running an RDP server: containers usually only run one process and it's not a desktop server.